# Are electric fields produced by static electric charges different from those produced by time-varying magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I came across an interesting yet perplexing statement in my physics textbook:

> However, we hasten to add that electric fields produced by static electric charges have properties different from those produced by time-varying magnetic fields.

My questions are, simply put:
*What exactly are these properties? And why do they differ?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference is in the structure of the fields:

- The field contribution from static charges are non-rotational (curl-free) but divergent.
- The field contributions from time-varying magnetic fields are divergence-less but have non-zero curl.

You can read this right out of the Gauss and Faraday's Laws in their differential form:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{\nabla \cdot E} &= \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} \\
\\
\mathbf{\nabla \times E} &= - \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t} \;.
\end{align*}
The operators on the LHSs are called "[divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence)" and "[curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics))" (read top to bottom).

---

I hasten to add that these are exactly the same kind of stuff, which is why I've written "contributions from" rather than "fields produced by" as if the fields might be of different kinds. In the presence of both static charges and varying magnetic field the total electric field will show *both* divergence and curl.

Comment: Got it... it's clear now. Danke.

Comment: You beat me @dmckee ;/

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline\textrm{True in Statics} &\textrm{True in General}\\ \hline \mathbf F ~= \dfrac1{4\pi\varepsilon_o}~ \dfrac{q_1q_2}{r^2}~\mathbf{\hat r} & \mathbf F= q(\mathbf E+ \mathbf v\times \mathbf B)\\ \hline  \nabla \cdot \mathbf E = \dfrac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0} &  \nabla \cdot \mathbf E = \dfrac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}  \\ \hline \nabla\times \mathbf E= \mathbf 0& \nabla \times \mathbf E = ~-\partial_t\mathbf B\\ \hline \mathbf E= -\nabla\varphi & \mathbf E= -\nabla \varphi - \partial_t \mathbf A\\ \hline \nabla^2\varphi = -\dfrac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0} & \nabla^2\varphi -\dfrac1 {c^2}\partial^2_t\varphi = -\dfrac\rho{\varepsilon_0}\\ \hline \varphi(\mathbf 1)= \dfrac1{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\rho(\mathbf 2)}{r_{12}}~\mathrm dV_2 & \varphi(\mathbf 1, t)= \dfrac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\displaystyle \int \dfrac{\rho(\mathbf 2, t^\prime)}{r_{12}}~\mathrm dV_2\\\hline  U= \dfrac12 \left(\displaystyle\int \rho\varphi~\mathrm dV \right) & U= \dfrac{\varepsilon_0}2 \left(\displaystyle\int \mathbf E\cdot \mathbf E~\mathrm dV + {c^2}\displaystyle\int  \mathbf B\cdot \mathbf B~\mathrm dV\right)\\ \hline\end{array}$$

where

\begin{align}\mathbf F& \equiv \textrm{Total force},\\ \mathbf E& \equiv \textrm{Electric field},\\ \mathbf B &\equiv \textrm{Magnetic field},\\ \nabla &\equiv \textrm{del operator},\\ \rho &\equiv\textrm{Charge-density},\\ \varphi &\equiv \textrm{Scalar-potential},\\ \mathbf A &\equiv \textrm{Vector-potential},\\ \partial_t &\equiv  \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t},\\ \nabla^2 &\equiv \textrm{Lapalacian operator},\\ \partial^2_t &\equiv \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2},\\   U &\equiv \textrm{Potential-energy}, \\ t^\prime &\equiv \textrm{retarded-time} = t-\dfrac{r_{12}}c\;.  \end{align}

Comment: How do you have $\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{E}$?

Comment: @Mehrdad: _Electrostatics...._

Comment: Electrostatics can make force and field have the same units??

Comment: @Mehrdad: Sorry, lack of attentiveness; would fix this. Thanks for pointing out that.

Comment: Mafia, I downvoted this because it gives a table and a list of terms, but it doesn't _explain_ anything.

Comment: Okay, that may be a good point, @JohnDuffield; could you tell me what to add more to make it better?

Comment: Mafia, to make it better you could say something about the distinction between the force in statics and in general. Along the lines of _"when (two or more) electromagnetic fields interact, the result is linear force and/or rotational force. When we only see a linear force we talk of an electric field, when we only see a rotational force we talk of a magnetic field. But in both cases the fields that are interacting are electromagnetic fields"_. Field and force are not the same thing.